# Unable to Pass ADODB.Recordset as a parameter to a function call

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, macros, byref

following is my declaration of recordset

```
    Dim expectedRs, actualRs As ADODB.Recordset

    Set expectedRs = accessDatabse.getResultSetForSqlQuery(tempArr(1))
    Set actualRs = accessDatabse.getResultSetForSqlQuery(tempArr(2))
```

the following works fine,

```
    excelFunc.writeQueryResultsToExcel( tempArr(0),   accessDatabse.getResultSetForSqlQuery(tempArr(1)),    accessDatabse.getResultSetForSqlQuery(tempArr(2)))
```

But, I cant pass the variables in the method call

```
    excelFunc.writeQueryResultsToExcel CStr(tempArr(0)), expectedRs,actualRs
```

I get an compile time error "ByRef Argument Type Mismatch"

Following is my function being Called

```
    Public Function writeQueryResultsToExcel(workbookName As String, expectedRs As Object, actualRs As Object)

        Dim wkb As Workbook
        Dim strPath As String

        strPath = globalObj.getDefaultRunInstancePath()

        Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(strPath + workbookName + ".xlsx")

        'rs.Open strSQL
        'Sheet4.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
    '***********************************UntestedCode******************************
        wkb.Sheets("Expected").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset expectedRs
        wkb.Sheets("Actual").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset actualRs
        wkb.Save
        wkb.Close
    '***********************************UntestedCode******************************

    End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim expectedRs, actualRs As ADODB.Recordset
```

Actually means:

```
Dim expectedRs As Variant, actualRs As ADODB.Recordset
```

And your function expects `expectedRs` to be `Object` and `actualRs` to be `Object` as well. Hence do the following changes:

```
Dim expectedRs, actualRs As ADODB.Recordset
```

change to:

```
Dim expectedRs As ADODB.Recordset, actualRs As ADODB.Recordset
```

and

```
Public Function writeQueryResultsToExcel(workbookName As String, expectedRs As Object, actualRs As Object)
```

change to:

```
Public Function writeQueryResultsToExcel(workbookName As String, expectedRs As ADODB.Recordset, actualRs As ADODB.Recordset)
```

Comment: Thanks @emihir0 , my problem has been resolved, your efforts are much appreciated.